# How can I do a post and delete request front end UI

Tags: jquery, crud

So I am trying to excute a put method and delete method on the front end UI I was able to get the GET and POST working but I am trying to do a PUT and DELETE going when ever I execute my PUT it does not execute no error messages show up on the console and also I have CORS enabled in my web browser

```js
$(function(){
$("#showMovies").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
     const rowText = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
        $("#movies").append(rowText);
      });
      loadButton();
    }
  });
});
function getOneMovie(id){
          $.ajax({
              url: 'http://localhost:3000/movielist' + id,
              method: 'get',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) {
                  $($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(data._id);
                  $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(data.intNum);
                  $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(data.name);
                  $($("#updateForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(data.thumnail_path);
                  $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(data.description);
                  $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(data.year_released);
                  $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(data.language_released);
                  $("#updateForm").show();
              }
          });
      }
$("#movieAdded").click(function(a){
  let mydata = {
    idmovielist: $($("#newForm")[0].intNum).val(),
    name:$($("#newForm")[0].name).val(),
    thumnail_path:$($("#newForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
    description:$($("#newForm")[0].description).val(),
    year_released:$($("#newForm")[0].year_released).val(),
    language_released:$($("#newForm")[0].language_released).val(),
  }
  displayMovie(mydata);
       $("#newForm").trigger("reset");
       $("#newForm").toggle();
       a.preventDefault();
});
function displayMovie(data) {
  $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
    }
});
}
function loadButton() {
        $(".editMovie").click(function(e){
          ($(this)[0]).data("idmovielist");
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $(".deleteMovie").click(function(e){
            deleteTutorial($($(this)[0]).data("idmovielist"));
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

    function putTutorial(data){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/movielist/update/3',
            method: 'PUT',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                getOneMovie();
            }
        });
    }

    $("#updateMovie").on("click", function(e) {
       let data = {
         idmovielist: $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(),
         name:$($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(),
         thumnail_path:$($("#updataForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
         description:$($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(),
         year_released:$($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(),
         language_released:$($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(),
       }

       putTutorial($($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(), data);
           $("#updateForm").trigger("reset");
           $("#updateForm").toggle();
           e.preventDefault();

    });



    function deleteMovie(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/" + id,
            method: 'DELETE',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

So this is my code in jquery I made an update form in my html if you guys need to see that as well just let me know I wonder if I am missing something or if something is undefined

Comment: What are you using for the web server? You may need to enable PUT and DELETE either via GUI (like with IIS) or with web.config or httpd.conf file.

Comment: @mark.hch I am using chrome

Comment: " I have CORS enabled in my web browser" ...What do you mean by this exactly?Browsers enable CORS protection by default. Usually switching it off involves installing some 3rd party add-in. The place where you will need to add the relevant CORS headers is on your _server_, whenever you send a response to these requests (and also to the preflight OPTIONS requests that will likely be generated by the browser when you try to run them). I suggest you read more about CORS so you understand the mechanics. Here's a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Chrome isn't a web server. It's a web browser. Web server would be the thing serving up your web pages - like IIS, Apache, Nginx, Glassfish, etc. Also, CORS (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing) only affects Cross-Origin requests. It looks like all your links are localhost, which would be the same origin (unless you're sending requests to a different port than the site you're sending the requests from).

Comment: @mark.hch the issue that I am having is that when ever I execute my put and delete I am not getting any response from the network tab not status code nothing is something wrong with my CORS